# PHP RSA encryption openssl issue

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, rsa

I have been racking my brain.  I am using the latest version of php 7.  I can get rsa working with short text, however long text seems to not work.  I read to use openssl_seal/open.. when I demoed the code on a test page it works great.. when I put it into practice with mysql its not working the way its supposed to..

Encryption code:

```
$messageiv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
openssl_seal($_POST[$_SESSION['message']], $encryptedmessage, $ekeys, array($_SESSION['recipient_publickey']), "AES256", $messageiv);
openssl_seal($_POST[$_SESSION['subject']], $encryptedsubject, $ekeys, array($_SESSION['recipient_publickey']), "AES256", $messageiv);
```

The above is then base91_encoded and stored into blobs/varchar.

To decrypt it

```
openssl_open(base91_decode($row['messagesubject']), $decryptedsubject, $ekeys[0], $_SESSION['privatersakey'], "AES256", base91_decode($row['messageiv']));              
    openssl_open(base91_decode($row['messagebody']), $decryptedbody, $ekeys[0], $_SESSION['privatersakey'], "AES256", base91_decode($row['messageiv']));
```

The above variables $decryptedsubject and $decryptedmessage are blank.

I had this issue before using openssl_public/private key encrypt/decrypt and added the padding, this worked, however with long text it won't encrypt/decrypt....

Any assistance would be great...

Answer (score 2):

> I can get rsa working with short text, however long text seems to not work.

This is expected. RSA only operates on short inputs. If you want to encrypt a long message with RSA, you need to do one of two things:

1. Break your message into several distinct chunks and encrypt them separately. This is slow, inefficient, and insecure. (Attackers can drop or reorder chunks.)
2. Use a secure construction combining RSA and AES, [like so](https://paragonie.com/blog/2018/04/protecting-rsa-based-protocols-against-adaptive-chosen-ciphertext-attacks#rsa-hybrid).

Thus, you end up with something like this:

- Encryption

  1. Generate a random 32-byte key, `k`.
  2. Encrypt `k` with your RSA public key to get `C`.
  3. Calculate the HMAC-SHA256(`C`, `k`) to get the message key `m`.
  4. Encrypt your message (`P`) with `m`, using AES-256-GCM to get `D`.
  5. Return `C` and `D`.
- Decryption

  1. Generate a random dummy key, which we'll call `k'`.
  2. Decrypt `C` using your RSA private key, to obtain `k` (one-time AES key).
  3. If step 2 failed, use a constant-time algorithm to swap `k` out for `k'`.
  4. Calculate the HMAC-SHA256(`C`, `k`) to get the message key `m`.
  5. Decrypt `D` using `m`.
  6. Return the decrypted plaintext (or fail because of the authentication tag).

> I read to use openssl_seal/open.. when I demoed the code on a test page it works great.. when I put it into practice with mysql its not working the way its supposed to..

First, consider [using libsodium instead](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/06/libsodium-quick-reference-quick-comparison-similar-functions-and-which-one-use#crypto-box-seal).

Whether or not you continue to use OpenSSL, you probably want to base64-encode your output (and make sure you're storing data in a text field rather than a short varchar).